# Cannot set selected style for LinkButton which inside a repeater control

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, linkbutton

I have a repeater control in my aspx page:

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <img src="pic/iconnew.jpg"/>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="linkbtTitle" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("title")%>' CommandArgument='<%#Eval("id_notic")%>' OnCommand="linkbtTitle_Click" OnClick="Buttonlink_Click" ></asp:LinkButton>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Label ID="LabelTime" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("time")%>' CssClass="TimeMessage" ></asp:Label> 
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
```

I want to set the selected style for linkbutton `linkbtTitle` by `Buttonlink_Click` event:

```
<script runat="server">  
    protected void Buttonlink_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)  
    {
        linkbtTitle.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.HotPink;  
    }  

</script>
```

But it has an error, cannot resolve symbol `linkbtTitle` , why??? Just because the linkbutton is inside the Repeater so I cannot access it by that way above.

How???, help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A repeater is one of the web-databound controls that, well, it repeats items. So there are normally more than one item. That's why you cannot access it directly. It sits in a different `NamingContainer` which is the `RepeaterItem` of the repeater.

However, the control that raised an event is always the `sender` argument. So you just need to cast it:

```
protected void Buttonlink_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)  
{
    LinkButton linkbtTitle =  (LinkButton ) sender;       
    linkbtTitle.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.HotPink;  
}
```

Comment: thanks, that is all I need, so great. I'm waiting for out of 10mins to vote your answer. Thanks again!